# Rails 6.1.4 counter_cache issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I develop simple app which has Issue and IssueStep models.
I'm not sure if I missed something with counter_cache because it not works as expected for relation defined with custom name and class_name.

```rb
issue.steps.size - fire count() in DB, why? 
issue.issue_steps.size - uses counter_cache
issue.issue_steps_count - has correct values and I use it now
```

```rb
class IssueStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :issue, counter_cache: true
end

class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :steps, class_name: 'IssueStep', foreign_key: 'issue_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :issue_steps # added for test only 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you have to do to make it work

1. Change the counter column name in the `Issue` table to `steps_count`
2. In `IssueStep` model replace your code with the following

```
  belongs_to :issue, counter_cache: :steps_count
```

Now you should be able to to get the cached value using `issue.steps.size`

> This is how Rails find the cached column name: [link to official source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/70bbc3706bc97e4e75cc37affb8b35958c1f2d83/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L214)